# Como melhorar este método que compara três números?

Tags: swift, swift-playground

Podem me ajudar a melhorar este pequeno código, de forma a ser menos extensa e limpa?

O código compara três números e mostra qual e o maior entre eles:

```
@IBAction func comprar(_ sender: Any) {

    if pNumero.text! > sNumero.text! {
        messageLabel.text = "Primeiro número e maior"
    }

    else if pNumero.text! < sNumero.text! {
        messageLabel.text = "Segundo número e maior"
    }

    if tNumero.text! > pNumero.text!{
        messageLabel.text = "o Terceiro número e maior"
    }


    else if tNumero.text! < sNumero.text! {
        messageLabel.text = "o Terceiro número e maior"
    }

    else if pNumero.text! == sNumero.text!{
        messageLabel.text = "Os dois números são iguais"

    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nunca utilizei swift na minha vida, mas arriscarei uma resposta.

```
@IBAction func comprar(_ sender: Any) {

    var maior = pNumero.text!

    messageLabel.text = "Primeiro número e maior"

    if sNumero.text! > maior {
        maior = sNumero.text!
        messageLabel.text = "Segundo número e maior"
    }

    if tNumero.text! > maior {
        maior = tNumero.text!
        messageLabel.text = "Terceiro número e maior"
    }

}
```

### Explicação

Você armazena sempre o maior valor em uma variável e compara as outras com este valor. Se o novo valor for maior, atualiza a variável. No início, é considerado o primeiro número como sendo o maior, pois não há valor para compará-lo. Verificamos se o segundo valor é maior que o primeiro. Se sim, `maior` passa a ter o valor de `sNumero`, se não, mantém o valor de `pNumero`. Após, verificamos se o terceiro número é maior que `maior`. Se sim, atualizamos o valor de `maior` com o valor de `tNumero`, se não, mantém o valor atual.

Uma variação deste código, com a mesma lógica, pode ser vista em funcionamento [aqui](https://repl.it/F50n/0).

Comment: Ai Anderson, obrigado pela ajuda. A ideia é, o usuário vai inserir 3 números  e os if e else analisam qual é o maior numero dos três. 

* Agora penso em igual uma condição que diz qual é o maior numero e o melhor dos três inseridos

Comment: Melhor dos três?

Comment: Maior número dos três

Comment: https://repl.it/F50n/0, veja aqui funcionando.

Comment: Funcionou, perfeitamente!

Comment: Marque a resposta como válida, se possível.

Comment: Done !!!!!!!!!!